# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.resources'

Tags: linux, pip, python-importlib, netmiko

So I'm working on a project where I should work with Netmiko. I had installed the module using `pip3 install netmiko` command and it installed successfully. But, when I try to `import netmiko` module in the python3 console, it throws an error saying "Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.resources".

The next step I took was trying to install `pip install importlib-resources` and still faced the same issue.

Sorry guys I'm a newbie, need some help with this one.

Comment: It could be an issue with pip and pip3 both existing and being different…

Comment: Are you sure you are running your code in correct directory?

Comment: What version of Python do you use? Send an output from the `python3 -V` command. Netmiko seems to be working with Python 3.7 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in import in the file reporting the error from importlib.resource to importlib_resources.

I had the same problem and found that solution online, it worked for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I'd rather don't recommend to edit pip-installed libraries. It may fix the issue but you will have to apply the same patch again wherever you run your program. There is likely a better way to fix it. I could help to find it if you provide versions info: OS, Python interpreter version, netmiko version.